# Elasticsearch java API query behavior strangeness

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm having some trouble fully understanding the behavior of an elasticsearch query that I'm attempting to build with the java API (v1.7.1).  Below is the initial `SearchRequestBuilder`;

```
SearchRequestBuilder builder = client.prepareSearch("my_index")
            .setTypes("my_document_type")
            .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH);
```

I have a collection of indexed documents with both a `title` and `content` field.  When I attempt to match phrases within the `title` field like so;

```
builder.setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("title", keyword));
```

And then of course;

```
SearchResponse response = builder.execute().actionGet();
```

The behavior of this query works exactly as I expect - my searches return highly relevant results based off of the contents of the `title` field - so far so good.

However when I attempt to add another query to the builder;

```
builder.setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("content", keyword));
```

My original very relevant results (based off of title content) are now much less understandable.  For instance, a search phrase (keyword) "this is a test" would return documents where that phrase existed word-for-word (in the title) - like I said, perfect.  However the addition of the second query now makes those previously relevant documents drop from the results entirely - nowhere to be found.  Even though the same text is being matched against the same field as before.  Clearly I'm doing something wrong, I just don't understand what - or how to realize the desired behavior which is to match keywords against both `title` and `content` and return relevant results, meaning if there is a very close phrase match in `title` I would expect to see those documents scored higher.  I've also tried boosting to no effect;

```
builder.setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("title", keyword).boost(5.0f));
builder.setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("content", keyword));
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling `setQuery` the second time you are not *adding* a query - you are (as the name suggests) *setting* the query, i.e. you replace the previously set query with the new one.

If you want to use both queries at the same time you need to [combine them](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bool-query.html) by using a compound query such as `bool`:

```
builder.setQuery(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .should(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("title", keyword).boost(5.0f))
    .should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("content", keyword)));
```